# Laravel on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I have a domain and a hosting already.

I want that http://example.com/ will already access the program.

Currently, I can only access the program using this
http://example.com/project/public

my current directory is this

> public_html
>
> > project
> >
> > > public

my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

my index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You are on shared hosting so you probably cannot edit apache configuration files to change Document root.

**So try this.**

Upload your laravel project to the same level as `public_html` (i.e **not inside** `public_html` but `public_html` and `your_project_dir` should be on the same level).

**Then soft link `public_html` to point to `your_project/public`**

```
$ ln -s /absolute_path/your_project_dir/public  /absolute_path/public_html
```

It should work now.

Comment: Hi sorry, this does not solved my question. It created a lot of /public links. The one that merely fix my issue is I did not created any soft link. Instead, /myproject and /public_html is same level, and I copied all the the public files to /public_html and it works. BUT, i have issues on git repository. Since public_html is not part of my repository, so it will not be updated at all.

Comment: I suggest you create another directory inside public_html and link that to your project's public dir. I am guessing the link to public_html was not created because you cannot link existing dirs. Follow my suggestion and make sure you change your document root to ` public_html/dir`

Answer (score 0):

basic address for shared hosting is: **DIR**.'/laravel/vendor/autoload.php
 and: **DIR**.'/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

Place your index.php in the public_html folder.